# Multithreading Entity Framework: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting

Tags: multithreading, entity-framework, dbcontext

So I have a windows service process that performs a workflow process. The back end uses Repository and UnitofWork Pattern and Unity on top of Entity Framework with the entities class generated from the edmx. I won't go into a whole lot of detail as its not necessary but basically there are 5 steps that the workflow goes through. A particular process might be at any stage at any point in time (in order of course). Step one just generates data for step two, which validates the data via a long running process to another server. Then step there generates a pdf with that data. For each stage we spawn a timer, however it is configurable to allow more than one timer to be spawned for each stage. Therein lays the problem. When I add a processor to a particular stage, it the following error randomly:

The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting.

Reading up on this it seems obvious that this is happening because the context is trying to access the same entity from two threads. But this is where it is kind of throwing me for a loop. All of the information I can find on this states that we should be using a instance context per thread. Which as far as I can tell I am doing (see the code below). I am not using singleton pattern or statics or anything so I am not really sure why this is happening or how to avoid it. I have posted the relevant bits of my code below for your review.

The base repository:

```
 public class BaseRepository
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a repository and registers with a <see cref="IUnitOfWork"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="unitOfWork"></param>
    public BaseRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        if (unitOfWork == null) throw new ArgumentException("unitofWork");
        UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a <see cref="DbSet"/> of entities.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">Entity type the dbset needs to return.</typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected virtual DbSet<TEntity> GetDbSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {

        return Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the state of an entity.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">object to set state.</param>
    /// <param name="entityState"><see cref="EntityState"/></param>
    protected virtual void SetEntityState(object entity, EntityState entityState)
    {
        Context.Entry(entity).State = entityState;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unit of work controlling this repository.       
    /// </summary>
    protected IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    protected virtual void Attach(object entity)
    {
        if (Context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
            Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    protected virtual void Detach(object entity)
    {
        Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides access to the ef context we are working with
    /// </summary>
    internal StatementAutoEntities Context
    {
        get
        {                
            return (StatementAutoEntities)UnitOfWork;
        }
    }
}
```

StatementAutoEntities is the autogenerated EF class.

The repository implementation:

```
public class ProcessingQueueRepository : BaseRepository, IProcessingQueueRepository
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new repository and associated with a <see cref="IUnitOfWork"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="unitOfWork"></param>
    public ProcessingQueueRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new <see cref="ProcessingQueue"/> entry in database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Queue">
    ///     <see cref="ProcessingQueue"/>
    /// </param>
    public void Create(ProcessingQueue Queue)
    {
        GetDbSet<ProcessingQueue>().Add(Queue);
        UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Updates a <see cref="ProcessingQueue"/> entry in database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="queue">
    ///     <see cref="ProcessingQueue"/>
    /// </param>
    public void Update(ProcessingQueue queue)
    {
        //Attach(queue);
        UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete a <see cref="ProcessingQueue"/> entry in database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Queue">
    ///     <see cref="ProcessingQueue"/>
    /// </param>
    public void Delete(ProcessingQueue Queue)
    {
        GetDbSet<ProcessingQueue>().Remove(Queue);  
        UnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a <see cref="ProcessingQueue"/> by its unique Id
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ProcessingQueue GetById(int id)
    {
        return (from e in Context.ProcessingQueue_SelectById(id) select e).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of <see cref="ProcessingQueue"/> entries by status
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="status"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IList<ProcessingQueue> GetByStatus(int status)
    {
        return (from e in Context.ProcessingQueue_SelectByStatus(status) select e).ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of all <see cref="ProcessingQueue"/> entries
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IList<ProcessingQueue> GetAll()
    {
        return (from e in Context.ProcessingQueue_Select() select e).ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the next pending item id in the queue for a specific work        
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serverId">Unique id of the server that will process the item in the queue</param>
    /// <param name="workTypeId">type of <see cref="WorkType"/> we are looking for</param>
    /// <param name="operationId">if defined only operations of the type indicated are considered.</param>
    /// <returns>Next pending item in the queue for the work type or null if no pending work is found</returns>
    public int GetNextPendingItemId(int serverId, int workTypeId, int? operationId)
    {
        var id = Context.ProcessingQueue_GetNextPending(serverId, workTypeId,  operationId).SingleOrDefault();
        return id.HasValue ? id.Value : -1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a list of <see cref="ProcessingQueueStatus_dto"/>s objects with all
    /// active entries in the queue
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IList<ProcessingQueueStatus_dto> GetActiveStatusEntries()
    {
        return (from e in Context.ProcessingQueueStatus_Select() select e).ToList();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Bumps an entry to the front of the queue 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="processingQueueId"></param>
    public void Bump(int processingQueueId)
    {
        Context.ProcessingQueue_Bump(processingQueueId);
    }
}
```

We use Unity for dependency injection, some calling code for example:

```
#region Members
    private readonly IProcessingQueueRepository _queueRepository;       
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>Initializes ProcessingQueue services with repositories</summary>
    /// <param name="queueRepository"><see cref="IProcessingQueueRepository"/></param>        
    public ProcessingQueueService(IProcessingQueueRepository queueRepository)
    {
        Check.Require(queueRepository != null, "processingQueueRepository is required");
        _queueRepository = queueRepository;

    }
    #endregion
```

The code in the windows service that kicks off the timers is as follows:

```
            _staWorkTypeConfigLock.EnterReadLock();
        foreach (var timer in from operation in (from o in _staWorkTypeConfig.WorkOperations where o.UseQueueForExecution && o.AssignedProcessors > 0 select o) 
                              let interval = operation.SpawnInternval < 30 ? 30 : operation.SpawnInternval 
                              select new StaTimer
                            {
                                Interval = _runImmediate ? 5000 : interval*1000,
                                Operation = (ProcessingQueue.RequestedOperation) operation.OperationId
                            })
        {
            timer.Elapsed += ApxQueueProcessingOnElapsedInterval;
            timer.Enabled = true;
            Logger.DebugFormat("Queue processing for operations of type {0} will execute every {1} seconds", timer.Operation, timer.Interval/1000);                
        }
        _staWorkTypeConfigLock.ExitReadLock();
```

StaTimer is just a wrapper on timer adding operation type. ApxQueueProcessingOnElapsedInterval then bascially just assigns work to the process based on the operation.

I will also add a bit of the ApxQueueProcessingOnElapsedInterval code where we are spawning tasks.

```
            _staTasksLock.EnterWriteLock();
        for (var x = 0; x < tasksNeeded; x++)
        {
            var t = new Task(obj => ProcessStaQueue((QueueProcessConfig) obj),
                             CreateQueueProcessConfig(true, operation), _cancellationToken);


            _staTasks.Add(new Tuple<ProcessingQueue.RequestedOperation, DateTime, Task>(operation, DateTime.Now,t));

            t.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(300); //so there are less conflicts fighting for jobs in the queue table
        }
        _staTasksLock.ExitWriteLock();
```

Comment: Does you IoC container `Dispose` the context instances?

Answer (score 28):

Looks like your service, repository and context are supposed to live for the whole life time of your application but that is incorrect. You can have multiple timers triggered at the same time. That means multiple threads will use your service in parallel and they will execute the code of your service in their thread = context is shared among multiple threads => exception because context is not thread safe.

The only option is to use a new context instance for each operation you want to execute. You can for example change your classes to accept context factory instead of context and get a new context for each operation.

Comment: I added a bit of the code to show how the services are being spawned. I am using a Task that spawns ProcessStaQueue which then works out what operation it should run. I know Context is not thread safe but given that I am not using statics or singleton pattern or anything, shouldnt a new context be instantiated independently for each task performed?

Comment: The service is ultimately being instantiated like this:
    ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IWhateverService>();

Does this maybe have something to do with it? My guess is that maybe is that maybe ServiceLocator has something to do with this.

Comment: But it is up to implementation of service locator if it creates a new instance of the service every time you ask for it or if it creates instance only for the first request and than reuses the instance.

Comment: lifetime is set to "perthread" for all of my objects in the configuration file.

Comment: Until .NET Core 2.1 is released, this is going to be a problem if you have a service method that does a transaction against multiple repository method calls. If you try to use a TransactionScope (as of 2.0), it will give you an exception.

Answer (score 8):

In case this helps anyone:

In my case, I did ensure that the non-thread-safe `DbContext` had a `TransientLifetime` (using Ninject), but it was still causing concurrency issues! Turns out that in some of my custom `ActionFilters` I used Dependency Injection to get access to the `DbContext` in the constructor, but `ActionFilters` have a lifetime that keeps them instantiated over multiple requests, so the context didn't get recreated.

I fixed it by manually resolving the dependency in the `OnActionExecuting` method instead of in the constructor so that it is a fresh instance every time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting this problem because I forgot the `await` keyword before one of my DAL function calls. Putting `await` there resolved it.